# Vertical scroll bar disappearing in Chrome (Bootstrap Tab)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

```html
<div class="tabs-wrap left relative nomargin" id="tabs">                  
                        <ul class="nav ultab" id="fram">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#history" data-toggle="tab" id="history1"  >History</a></li>
                             <li ><a href="#exam" data-toggle="tab" id="exam1" >Examination</a></li>
                             <li ><a href="#mdm" data-toggle="tab" id="mdm1" >MDM</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content" id="" >                 
                    <div class="tab-pane active scrolly" id="history">
                      <iframe name="iframe1" id="Frame1" class="frame" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%" src="1s.jsp"></iframe>
                     </div>                                  
                     <div class="tab-pane scrolly" id="exam" >
                      <iframe name="iframe2"  id="Frame2" class="frame" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0"  width="100%" src="2s.jsp"></iframe>
                     </div>                  
                     <div class="tab-pane scrolly" id="mdm" >
                      <iframe name="iframe3"  id="Frame3"  class="frame" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%"  src="3s.jsp"></iframe>
                     </div>  
                    </div> 
               </div>
```

vertical scroll bar is disappearing, when switch from one to next tab.
how to resolve it?

Comment: share your code to help u better

Comment: maybe because the content isnt high enough to scroll? => provide more content

Comment: Could you please add code snippet here. So identity your problem properly. :-)

Comment: Sir, I voted to keep your question open by accident, you're welcome.  (add some code)

Answer (score 0):

If you meen to keep the vertical scrollbar of your browser at all times you can add:

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

else you can a add the above code to any desired class:

```
.your-class {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If it is the tabs, you can create a class like `.scrolly` and add this class to all of your tabs, and then add this to your css:

```
.scrolly {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

These are just examples.

hope this helps :)